# Return code of doing an update query with ADOquery in Delphi to PostgreSQL

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I'm using  Adoquery with a Postgres database.
When I do an UPDATE or INSERT query the ExecSql nor the OPEN returns the number of affected records as it should , but always -1.
I use the newest version of psqlODBC : 09.01.0200.

Code:

```
Adoquery1.close;
Adoquery1.SQL.Clear;
query := 'insert into  testtabel (nummer, naam) values (3,''Barnsten'') ';
Adoquery1.SQL.Add(query ) ;
result := Adoquery1.ExecSql;
```

Result is -1

Comment: Why don't you just use the usual `Insert` and `Post` mechanism?

Comment: Maybe there is no DBAware control behind?

Comment: What happens if right after the call to `Adoquery1.ExecSQL;`, you add `AdoQuery1.Close; AdoQuery1.SQL.Text :=  `SELECT nummer, naam FROM testtabel where nummer = 3 and naam = ''Barnsten''); AdoQuery1.Open; ShowMessage('Result: ' + IntToStr(ADOQuery1.RowCount));`? Do you get `1`? If not, the `INSERT` failed, and the value you got from `RowsAffected` was correct. `Open` doesn't use `RowsAffected`; it uses `RowCount` instead, IIRC.

Comment: Is `testtabel` partitioned by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
function PerformSQL(const ASQL: string): integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if ASQL <> '' then
  begin
    ZQuery1.SQL.Text := ASQL;
    ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
    Result := ZQuery1.RowsAffected;
  end;
end;



 ShowMessage
    (IntToStr(PerformSQL('insert into test(te_id, te_code, te_name, te_type)' +
    ' VALUES(DEFAULT, 15, ''tezty68'', 1), (DEFAULT, 16, ''teztx75'', 1), (DEFAULT, 18, ''teztx89'', 1)')
    ));
```

Returns me 3.